# Chrome for Android back button showing odd behavior, Image not loading

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have implemented service worker on my website which is doing caching for me. I am running my website on chrome browser on android device. In some cases, when i click back button of chrome browser (i am offline) then my page data loads but images doesn't load from cache. But if i refresh the same page, then images load properly. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any examples.

Comment: Please add some examples in so that we can help.